# Hybris hmc localized variables not editable for admin user

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have the admin user, that should have all rights. 
But somehow I can't edit **all localized** fields when I logged in as admin.

For other users, I do not have this problem and all work fine. For example, admin100 in admin group have proper rights and can edit all fields.

I thought it could be changed access rights for admin, but it's same rights as for admin100.

I'm quite lost what it could be.

Comment: is that the issue concern all localized fields or just some of them ? did you check if this fields can be modified in the `item.xml`  (write="true") ?

Comment: it's for all localized fields(In product, in language at least). Correct me if I'm wrong, but if it was changed in items.xml it wouldn't be editable for all users. And in my case, only the admin could not edit them.

Comment: Make sure that no incorrect language is configured for that admin user, from HMC -> Languages Settings (top right corner)

Comment: As Mouad said, check the configured languages for your admin user `group`.

Comment: Thank you! I checked a lot of stuff but missed this one.